# Append array to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and it show arrays of a json url.

I want to append another json url arrays to my collectionView when user scroll to end of the collectionView. I do that like in this way but it didnt work. For example items in collectionView is 36 but in collectionView i see 6 of them in middle of page. My code :

```
- (void)loadMore {

NSString *path = @"https://example.com/?json=get_posts&page=2";

path = [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

NSArray *array = json[@"posts"];

self.contentArray = [self.contentArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array];

NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.contentArray.count);

[self.contentCollection reloadData];

}
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.contentCollection numberOfSections] -1;
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.contentCollection numberOfItemsInSection:lastSectionIndex] -1;
    if ((indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex) && (indexPath.row == lastRowIndex)) {
        [self loadMore];
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that "loadMore" function never called ?

Comment: No, It called but didnt work right. See comment of answer. @AliOmari

Comment: is your delegate set?

Comment: Yes I set that in storyboard @DishantRajput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fix this with below code :

in my ViewController.h :

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) int page;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *contentArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UICollectionView *contentCollection;
```

And in my ViewController.m :

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView willDisplayCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [self.contentCollection numberOfSections] - 1;
NSInteger lastRowIndex = [self.contentCollection numberOfItemsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
if ((indexPath.section == lastSectionIndex) && (indexPath.item == lastRowIndex)) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://example.com/?json=get_posts&page=%d",self.page];

    path = [path stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:[NSCharacterSet URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet]];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];
    NSArray *array = json[@"posts"];

    self.contentArray = [self.contentArray arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:array];

    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.contentArray.count);
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
    [self.contentCollection reloadData];
        self.page = self.page + 1;
        });
    });
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.contentArray = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *array = json[@"posts"];
[self.contentArray addObjectsFromArray: array];
NSLog(@"%ld",(long)self.contentArray.count);
```

// For array use this addObjectsFromArray

Comment: No, i didnt want to remove first items. For Example FaceBook or Instagram, when you scroll to end of page, new items show.

Answer (score 0):

Don't reinitialize `self.contentArray`.

Just do `[self.contentArray addObjectsFromArray:array];`
It will append the new objects to the old array.
But make sure that `contentArray` is a `NSMutableArray`.